# Cordova Plug-in result not sent on first time

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

My Cordova Plug-in is only sending the `CDVPluginResult` on the second call. The first call always fails.

This is what I am doing:

```js
let dataQR : [AnyHashable : Any] = [ "type" : "QRCode", "id" : qr ]
DispatchQueue.main.async {
  self.pluginresult = CDVPluginResult(status: CDVCommandStatus_OK, messageAs: dataQR)
  self.pluginresult.setKeepCallbackAs(true)
  self.plugin.commandDelegate.send(self.pluginresult, callbackId: self.command.callbackId)
}
```

The callback session must stay alive because the plug-in is also waiting for a response. The plug-in will be dismissed or kept running according to the response.

Comment: [`setKeepCallback()`](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/blob/master/framework/src/org/apache/cordova/PluginResult.java#L93) rather than `setKeepCallbackAs()` ?

Comment: No, for swift the method ´setKeepCallback´ is called ´setKeepCallbackAs´